# IntelliJ .idea folder is part of the local changes although it's defined in .gitignore

Tags: intellij-idea, gitignore

I have .idea in .gitignore as part of my project, but it still appears is local changes.

How can I fully ignore the .idea folder?

Here is my .gitignore definition:

```
.idea
.idea_modules/
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr
*.log

target/
```

Comment: Can you show us what's inside your `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

.idea folder was added to git changes.

Need to remove those file using:

```
git rm .idea -r --cached
```

And this will remove .idea folder from IntelliJ local changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should check and see whether the folder was previously added your repo. I believe if a file exists in the repo, you will see subsequent changes to it even if the file is excluded via `.gitignore`.